# Tor unexpectedly exited macOS

Tags: help, mac, support

I have MacBook Pro mid 2014 with macOS Sierra v.10.12.4 (16E195). After launching tor (v.7.0.2) produces a message:

[image]

After restarting nothing happens.

[image]

*Continue* button does nothing. *Copy Tor Log To Clipboard* button doesn't copy at all. Reinstalling doesn't help.

**How can I improve that?**